DIV не располагаются в строку
Я определил следующую таблицу стилей:
.data-table-wrapper {
    padding-top: 5vh;
    height: fit-content;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: black 3px solid;
    width: fit-content;
}

.row-elem {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 2px;
    width: fit-content;
}

у меня есть вот такой участок HTML разметки:
    <div class="data-table-wrapper">

        <!-- table of data from table in database -->

        <div class="row">

            <div class="row-elem">
                lorum ipsum
            </div>

            <div class="row-elem">
                lorum ipsum
            </div>

            <div class="row-elem">
                lorum ipsum
            </div>

            <div class="row-elem">
                lorum ipsum
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>

Сейчас этот участок отображается вот так. Как расположить блоки div класса ".elem-row" в строку?


display: inline-block; - позволит располагать в строку и задавать размеры

нет, не помогло, к сожалению, но спасибо

Элементы и так вроде располагаются в строку, но можете зафиксировать указав параметр flex-wrap: nowrap; или на уровень выше посмотрите, ничего ли не фиксирует ширину блока

@ЕвграфКотовский задайте достаточную ширину .data-table-wrapper и все должно получиться даже без display как написал LureRed

@LureRed, по умолчанию flex-flow: row nowrap

"Как расположить блоки div класса ".elem-row" в строку?" В коде нет элементов с классом elem-row :-(

Вот код и при этом, если будет переполнение, то они будут переходить на вторую строку из-за flex-wrap: wrap


.data-table-wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: fit-content;
}

.row-elem {
  background-color: green;
}
<div class="data-table-wrapper">

        <!-- table of data from table in database -->

        <div class="row">

            <div class="row-elem">
                lorum ipsum
            </div>

            <div class="row-elem">
                lorum ipsum
            </div>

            <div class="row-elem">
                lorum ipsum
            </div>

            <div class="row-elem">
                lorum ipsum
            </div>
            
            <div class="row-elem">
                lorum ipsum
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>



